# Android multiple shared elements not working with fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, shared-element-transition, fragment-transitions

I want to transition between fragments with two shared elements. But the problem is: only one gets animated.

The shared elements are taken from a viewHolder from list in the first fragment. The transitions I use are from Material library, exactly these ones https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/material-motion-with-mdc-c1f09bb90bf9

Fragment A:

```
fragmentManager.commit {
            replace([...])
            setReorderingAllowed(true)
            addSharedElement(viewA, viewA.transitionName)
            addSharedElement(viewB, viewB.transitionName)
            addToBackStack(fragmentClass.qualifiedName)
        }
```

Fragment B:

```
 sharedElementReturnTransition = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
            scrimColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
            duration = 3000L
            interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
        }
 binding.headerContainer.header.cover.transitionName = arguments?.getString("firstTrName") ?: return
 binding.headerContainer.title.cover.transitionName = arguments?.getString("secondTrName") ?: return
 binding.headerContainer.header.setImageResource(arguments?.getString("image") ?: return)
 binding.headerContainer.title.text = arguments?.getString("title") ?: return
```

It seems like only the last element that I added in the commit{} is the one that transitions. I have checked everything, transition names are unique, all data is there in the second fragment, all transition names, it's not an argument problem. Any ideas? Help would be highly appreciated, this is a very important client request.

Answer (score 1):

https://material.io/develop/android/theming/motion

> Unlike traditional Android shared elements, it is not designed around
> a singular piece of shared content, such as an image, to be moved
> between two scenes. Instead, the shared element here refers to the
> bounding container of a start View or ViewGroup (e.g. the entire row
> layout of an item in a list) transforming its size and shape into that
> of an end View or ViewGroup (e.g. the root ViewGroup of a full screen
> Fragment). These start and end container Views are the “shared
> element” of a container transform. While these containers are being
> transformed, their contents are swapped to create the transition.

Two shared element doesn't work properly. When selecting start view  from the top of the list, ***imageView*** becomes a container. When selecting from the bottom, ***textView*** becomes a container. (See difference between example1 and example5 from the gif below)

You can use traditional shared element transition instead of Material Motion.

---

**EXAMPLE AND GIF**

```
fragmentEnd.sharedElementEnterTransition = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
    scrimColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    containerColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    duration = 1000L
    interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
}

fragmentEnd.sharedElementReturnTransition = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
    scrimColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    containerColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    duration = 1000L
    isElevationShadowEnabled = false
    interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
}

val manager: FragmentManager = activity.supportFragmentManager
manager.beginTransaction()
        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
        .addSharedElement(imageView, imageView.transitionName)
        .addSharedElement(textView, textView.transitionName)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .replace([...])
        .commit()
```

[image]

---

**SOLUTION**

You can change transition like this:

```
fragmentEnd.sharedElementEnterTransition = getTransition() 
fragmentEnd.sharedElementReturnTransition = getTransition() 

private fun getTransition(): Transition{
    val set = TransitionSet()
    set.ordering = TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER
    set.addTransition(ChangeBounds())
    set.addTransition(ChangeImageTransform())
    set.addTransition(ChangeTransform())
    return set
}
```

---

***Proper way of using MaterialContainerTransform:***

- Share one element

  ```
    fragmentEnd.sharedElementEnterTransition = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
        scrimColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        containerColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(activity.resources,R.color.purple_amethyst,null)
        duration = 1000L
        startShapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel().withCornerSize(100f)
        interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
    }


   fragmentEnd.sharedElementReturnTransition = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
        scrimColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        containerColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(activity.resources,R.color.purple_amethyst,null)
        duration = 1000L
        endShapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel().withCornerSize(100f)
        interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
    }


    val manager: FragmentManager = activity.supportFragmentManager
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
            .addSharedElement(imageView, imageView.transitionName)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .replace([...])
            .commit()
  ```
- FragmentEnd Layout:

  ```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:background="@color/purple_amethyst">

       <....../>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  ```
- Set transition name to top layout of fragmentEnd

  ```
  ViewCompat.setTransitionName(binding.container, getArguments().getString("imageViewTransitionName"));
  ```

**RESULT**

[image]